# Is there a way to - by default - have the text box in Microsoft Paint (Windows 10) smaller than the default size it makes when you click to add text?

Tags: microsoft-paint

If I only want a text box to have say, the number "7" in it, I have to resize the text box to make it smaller than the default size every time.

I know that you can make the text box larger by holding down the cursor and dragging to make the box bigger before you start typing, but I want to know if there is any way to make it smaller by default, so I don't have to resize it manually every time I want to insert a number or letter or two in an image.

Comment: why would you have to do this? ... the text box  has a transparent background ... you can simply type `7` in a large text box and then move the text box if you need to

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set the default text (in a text box) in Microsoft Paint.

Please see [Microsoft Paint text box](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-default-font-size-in-ms-paint/16203e1e-dd73-4723-90fe-875a3d61869e)

> I understand your concern. Unfortunately, there is no built-in method
> within Microsoft Paint or a registry hack to change the default font
> size. Regardless of how many times you change it in a session, it will
> always revert back to 11pt upon opening a new document.